# Blender inset faces not working with small angle

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

[image]

I want to inset face in it but after I press "I" it went like the second pic. Anyone know how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just try to add some geometry manually here before insetting?. Like with the knife tool.

[image: geometry solution]

Comment: I tried it but the same problem occur...